# Laravel 4.2 blade: check if empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel blade you can do:

```
{{ $variable or 'default' }}
```

This will check if a variable is set or not. I get some data from the database, and those variables are always set, so I can not use this method.

I am searching for a shorthand 'blade' function for doing this:

```
{{ ($variable != '' ? $variable : '') }}
```

It is hard to use this piece or code for doing this beacuse of, I do not know how to do it with a link or something like this:

```
<a href="{{ $school->website }}" target="_blank">{{ $school->website }}</a>
```

I tried:

```
{{ ($school->website != '' ? '<a href="{{ $school->website }}" target="_blank">{{ $school->website }}</a>' : '') }}
```

But, it does not work. And, I would like to keep my code as short as possible ;)

Can someone explain it to me?

**UPDATE**

I do not use a foreach because of, I get a single object  (one school) from the database. I passed it from my controller to my view with:

```
 $school = School::find($id);
 return View::make('school.show')->with('school', $school);
```

So, I do not want to make an `@if($value != ''){}` around each $variable (like $school->name).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this:

```
@if ($value !== '')
    {{ HTML::link($value,'some text') }}
@endif
```

Comment: Indeed, that is a solution instead of typing <a href=... but, I do not want an if around each line of my code. I prefer a shorthand  solution, so my code will be easier to read.

Comment: @Marten As you told above,your solution would not worked.At least mine works :) But I agree with you about being shorthand

Comment: @Marten I suggest you to edit your question and tell me how many variables you have in your view.maybe with a `foreach()` your problem will be solved

Comment: @Marten You can write the if on one line without a problem `@if($value != '') {{ HTML::link($value, 'some text') }} @endif`

Comment: @lukasgeiter, I am going to use your method. And for the values without <a href.. I will use {{ ($value != '' ? $value : '') }}. Thanks!

Comment: @Marten Why even do this? `{{ ($variable != '' ? $variable : '') }}` this means if the $variable is `''` print out `''`. Why don't just print it like it is: `{{ $variable }}`

Comment: @lukasgeiter You're right! I am sorry, I mean this {{ ($variable != '' ? $variable : '-') }} (with a -) ;)

Comment: @Marten Ahhhh! yeah that makes more sense :)

Answer (score 15):

I prefer the [`@unless` directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#if-statements) for readability in this circumstance.

```
@unless ( empty($school->website) )
    <a href="{{ $school->website }}" target="_blank">{{ $school->website }}</a>
@endunless
```

Answer (score 9):

With php 7, you can use null coalescing operator. This is a shorthand for @m0z4rt's answer.

```
{{ $variable ?? 'default' }}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
{{ ($school->website != '' ? '<a href="{{ $school->website }}" target="_blank">{{ $school->website }}</a>' : '') }}
```

change to

```
{{ ($school->website != '') ? '<a href="' . $school->website . '" target="_blank">' .  $school->website . '</a>' : '' }}
```

or the same code

```
{{ ($school->website != '') ? "<a href='$school->website' target='_blank'>$school->website</a>" : '' }}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ isset($variable) ? $variable : 'default' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why nobody talked about `$variable->isEmpty()` it looks more better than other. Can be used like:

```
@if($var->isEmpty())
    Do this  
@else
    Do that  
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel 5.4, you can also use the **@isset** directive.

```
@isset($variable)
    {{-- your code --}}
@endisset
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#if-statements